# Is this a valid C statement?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Let's say I write `char c[99] = {'Stack Overflow'};` in C or C++. It compiles fine but is this valid? By valid I meant not invoking any kind of undefined or unspecified behavior.

Again if I write `char c[99] = 'Stack Overflow';` gcc complains about multicharacter constant which is obvious but in the above when I am enclosing within curly brackets compiler is happy! Why is it so?

I also notice that `puts(c);` after the first statement will output 'w' precisely the last character of a general string in-place of `Stack Overflow`.  Why so?

Could somebody explain these behaviors separately?

Comment: Compile it and find out.

Comment: He already said he did compile it...

Comment: @Falmarri: I think you win the RTFQ award.  He said "it compiles fine" and also describes the output, obviously he did test it.  But testing doesn't tell you whether it's portable or well-defined by the standard.

Comment: @Falmarri:  compiling it will never tell you if it evokes UB.

Comment: try to replace ' with " and reask this question )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They both are only a single literal, so `c[0]` gets set to the literal and `c[1]` ... `c[98]` get filled with zero (NUL character).

I think what value actually gets stuffed into `c[0]` is implementation dependent, but it should at least compile on any compliant compiler.

EDIT: Verified against the standard, in C++0x at least:

> A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined value.

And in C99 (using [the draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), cause it's free):

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-deﬁned.

Comment: Hm but why the statement with curly brackets passes the syntactic checking of the compiler?

Comment: @Philando: Because it's a "compound initializer" being used to initialize an array?  That's perfectly legal.  There's no rule that compound initializers have to have more than one element, in fact things like `int a[10] = { 0 };` are very common.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: +1,Thanks for your time,but I am more interested in knowing what C about to say for this expression.:) I mean the last character thing,but I guess I should take this as implementation defined?

Comment: @Philando: Well, you did tag it `[c++]`.  Looking for the relevant section in C99 now.

Comment: My apologies.I tagged so that it gets through more eyeballs also I guess it would not be much difference Isn't ? + my observation is valid for both C and C++ :)

Comment: @Philando: Relevant part of C99 found.  It makes it implementation defined as well.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I really appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: @Philando: Tag it with the language you're using. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @Philando, @GMan: Tagging as both C and C++ isn't necessarily a problem, but if you're not looking for an answer from either-or, you should probably make that doubly clear in the question body.

Comment: Even if `c` were not an array, putting the braces around the initializer would be valid. C **always** allows braces around initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - in Windows Kernel code - you see a lot of tagging memory.  And it's actually implemented per platform.  However, they use ULONGs to tag memory, and it's always a 4-character literal in reverse order:
ULONG tagMemory = 'kscf';

The interpretation is platform-specific, but a stream of characters.